# Ionic 3 / TypeScript / Angular : how to handle SQLite database callbacks within FOR loop

Tags: angular, sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have following pages in my LibraryApp , developing using Ionic 3 framework

- CategoryPage : To add new record in Category table
- BookPage : To add new record in Book table
- Transaction: To add daily transaction where TrxType is either "BookIssued" or "BookReturned"
- CategorySummaryPage: summary for each CategoryID as on specific day
- StudentSummaryPage: summary for each StudentID as on specific day

and have following tables:

- Category(ID INTEGER,Name TEXT)
- Book(ID INTEGER,CategoryID INTEGER,Title TEXT)
- Transaction(TrxID INTEGER, TrxDate TEXT,TrxType TEXT,BookID INTEGER,DueReturnDate TEXT)
- Student(StudentID INTEGER,StudentName TEXT)
- CategorySummary(SummaryDate TEXT,CategoryID INTEGER,TotalBooksIssued INTEGER,TotalBooksReturned INTEGER)
- StudentSummary(SummaryDate TEXT,StudentID INTEGER,TotalBooksIssued INTEGER,TotalBooksReturned INTEGER)

How to handle following scenario(which is not working as expected) where multiple callback methods to database are called within FOR Loop

```
GetAllCategory().then(categoryRecs => {
 for(index=0;index < categoryRecs.length;index++)
 {
   this.objCategorySummary.categoryID=categoryRecs[index].CategoryID;
   GetAllCategoryForCategoryID(categoryRecs[index].CategoryID)
   .then(trxRecs => {
       //This method will populate other fields of this.objCategorySummary
      this.calculateCategorySummary(trxRecs);
      this.addCategorySummary(this.objCategorySummary)
        .then(res=> {
        console.log("SUCCESS:CategorySummary populated !");
        }).catch(e => console.log("Error:addCategorySummary " + e));
   }).catch(e => console.log("Error:GetAllCategoryForCategoryID " + e));  
 }//end of for loop
}).catch(e => console.log("Error:GetAllCategory " + e));
```